# Detect Direction of Camera movement?

Tags: roblox

So in my game, I need to be able to detect which direction the player moves his camera in(right/left,up/down) However, I couldn't find a property of Camera that is the angle in which it is pointing at, so I couldn't figure out how to detect if the player was moving his camera right or left. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current rotation of the camera by utilizing the `Camera.CFrame` property. In terms of checking if the camera is moving right or left, I would recommend reading into how [CFrame](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=CFrame) angles function.